# Using Async/Await with npm request module

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, npm-request

I am currently trying to send some request with the npm request module.
The normal callback variant works very well but I am not able to do the same with async await.

At first I tried to do it with 'request-promise-native' module but I am not able to even run a normal promise example.

```
var request = require('request-promise-native');
request(login)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Post succeeded with status %d", response.statusCode);})
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Error");
        });
```

I am not sure what I do  wrong but the .then function is called and the response attribute is completely empty. If I look in webstorm debug I see only giberisch � inside that value. screenshot:

[image]

My final goal is to use the npm request module like that:

var result = await request(login);

And in the result is either the response or an error if that is not possible I also can use the promise only variant.

Can somebody tell me what I do wrong or how to do it correctly?

Regards
Ruvi

Edit: Ok I found out what the first problem was. 
      The server I was contacting send gzip info and I needed to put gzip = true in my options object and now I get a readable answer.
But my problem is not solved:

if I use:

```
req(login, function(error, response, body){
        if (error)
         console.log(error);

        console.log(body);
        console.log(response.statusCode);
    });
```

I get the complete request and response object. From the Request module.
If I use:

```
 var result = await req(login);
```

I get as result the request object but without the response object and response header information.

This returns me only the response body only one variable is filled:

```
request(login)
        .then(function (response, body) {
            console.log(response);})
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Error");
        });
```

How do I get promise and await to return me the whole request + response object?

Comment: have you tried to console.log only `response` and not `response.statusCode` ?

Comment: first, print response and see what you receive

Comment: Yes I get this if I console.log response:  �VJ,-�P�R2P�Q�M-.NLO�j� ��

Comment: @Ruvi can you update your question with screenshot

Comment: seems to be an encoding problem, see if you can set the response encoding to `utf8`

Comment: What version of node.js are you trying to use?

Answer (score 3):

To get the complete response object you have to add: resolveWithFullResponse=true
to the your options object that you pass to the request function

if you use:

```
var request = require('request-promise-native');

var result = await request(login);
//or
request(login)
        .then(function (response, body) {
            console.log(response);})
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Error");
        });
```

and both works fine and the complete request/response object is returned.

Comment: even then i still see the response as OP posted